# Extract data from API and store the records in a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am looking at the following website: https://data.gov.sg/dataset/bunker-sales-monthly?resource_id=44da3191-6c57-4d4a-8268-8e2c418d4b43 and they have the following example for extracting data using their API:

```py
    import requests
 
    result = []
    headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
    url = "https://data.gov.sg/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=44da3191-6c57-4d4a-8268-8e2c418d4b43"
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    data = r.json()
    print(data)
```

This produces the following, out of which I want to extract only the 'records' bit out of the output, and into a more readable format. Ideally, I want this data in a pandas data frame:

> {'records': [{'bunker_type': 'Marine Gas Oil', 'bunker_sales':
> '135.4', '_id': 1, 'month': '1995-01'}, {'bunker_type': 'Marine Diesel
> Oil', 'bunker_sales': '67.9', '_id': 2, 'month': '1995-01'},
> {'bunker_type': 'Marine Fuel Oil 180 cst', 'bunker_sales': '412.9',
> '_id': 3, 'month': '1995-01'}, {'bunker_type': 'Marine Fuel Oil 380
> cst', 'bunker_sales': '820.3', '_id': 4, 'month': '1995-01'},
> {'bunker_type': 'Marine Fuel Oil 500 cst +', 'bunker_sales': '0',
> '_id': 5, 'month': '1995-01'}...

In the format as below:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(columns=['month', 'bunker_type', 'bunker_sales'])
```

How could I go about extracting this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pd.json_normalize`:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data['result'], 'records')
print(df)

# Output:
                  bunker_type bunker_sales  _id    month
0              Marine Gas Oil        135.4    1  1995-01
1           Marine Diesel Oil         67.9    2  1995-01
2     Marine Fuel Oil 180 cst        412.9    3  1995-01
3     Marine Fuel Oil 380 cst        820.3    4  1995-01
4   Marine Fuel Oil 500 cst +            0    5  1995-01
..                        ...          ...  ...      ...
95  Ultra Low-Sulfur Fuel Oil            0   95  1995-08
96                     Others        102.2   96  1995-08
97             Marine Gas Oil        101.7   97  1995-09
98          Marine Diesel Oil           63   98  1995-09
99    Marine Fuel Oil 180 cst          395   99  1995-09

[100 rows x 4 columns]
```